# Subtracting float: 128.0 and int: 128 results in -5.6834188608e-14?

Tags: python

Still new to python so this is very weird to me...

```
def getNormalizedStart(self):
        # center is Point: {X = 300, Y = 128}
        center = self.getTargetCenterFromStart()

        # effectiveStart is Point: {X=300.0,Y=472}
        effectiveStart = self.getFirstActiveTouchEventLocations()[0]["Point"]\
            if self.isTouchTrial() else self.getFirstMouseEventLocation()

        radians = float(MathUtils.angle(effectiveStart, center, True))

        # Point: {X=-44.0,Y=128.0}
        newStart = MathUtils.rotatePoint(effectiveStart, center, -radians)

        # newStart.X is float: -44
        # center.X is int: 300
        newStart.X -= center.X    # the result is -344. Good!

        # newStart.Y is float: 128.0
        # center.Y is int: 128
        newStart.Y -= center.Y    # the result is -5.68434188608e-14. Wut?
        return newStart
```

But it works in the console:

```
>>> x = 128.0
>>> y = 128
>>> x -= y
>>> x
0.0
```

Am I going crazy or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Smells like a rounding error to me, but they're both powers of two, so it might be something else.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue with floating points operations in a computer is that in general, you can't get exact values. That's because it's impossible to exactly represent a number with decimals, and a simple operation such as `128.0 - 128` can lead to very small errors.

As usual the mandatory reading explaining this is [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: Right, but these are integer powers of two.  Those can be expressed exactly, can't they?

Comment: @John not necessarily. A decimal number with an exact representation in base-10 may have a non-exact, infinite representation when converted to base-2. The key word here is _decimal_. Even if the integer representation is exact, the decimal representation after performing an arithmetic operation might not be exact

Comment: I tried it in the console and it works.  Is there a reason why it worked there but not in the IDE?

Comment: Correct, but 128 is 2^7.  That's a terminating binary fraction.  I'd agree with you 100% if the OP was subtracting `67.0 - 67` but that it does it with 128 surprises me a little.

Comment: @icanc you're performing several operations with the values, it's possible that a rounding error propagated along the way

Answer (score 7):

I'm willing to bet your 128.0 isn't actually 128.

For example:

```
>>> print x
128.0
>>> print x-128
5.68434188608e-14
```

But I've cheated here: `x` is actually

```
>>> x
128.00000000000006
```

and there's a difference between the `str()` and `repr()`:

```
>>> str(x)
'128.0'
>>> repr(x)
'128.00000000000006'
```

I made this object by using `numpy.nextafter` to count two tiny increments above 128:

```
>>> numpy.nextafter(numpy.nextafter(128, 129),129)
128.00000000000006
```

To confirm this, you should check `repr(newStart.Y)` and `newStart.Y > 128`, and the same for `center.Y`, to see what they actually are.

[Edit: your difference is negative, so it's probably slightly less than 128 rather than slightly more, but you get the idea.]

Comment: Interesting, `repr(newStart.Y)` actually prints out `127.99999999999994` and `newStart.Y > 128` is `False`.

Comment: @icanc: yep, that makes sense.  So you have a number which is a tiny bit smaller than 128, but close enough that the `str()` shows it as being `128.0`, and so when you subtract exactly 128, you get the tiny little difference as the (negative) remainder.  Short version: don't trust `str()`, or `print somenumber`, to give you enough information to figure out floating point quirks. :^)